# Second overview ruler in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to add another overview ruler in Eclipse?
Maybe via a plugin?
It would be nice to assign certain annotations to different overview rulers.
For example the diffs in one overview ruler and the occurrences in another.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns` extension point to define a column in the editor ruler.

For example this is the standard definition for the annotation and line number columns:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns">
  <column
        class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.AnnotationColumn"
        enabled="true"
        global="true"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.editors.columns.annotations"
        includeInMenu="false"
        name="%AnnotationRuler.name">
     <placement
           gravity="0.5">
           <before id="org.eclipse.ui.editors.columns.linenumbers"/>
     </placement>
     <targetClass
           class="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor">
     </targetClass>
  </column>
  <column
        class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.LineNumberColumn"
        enabled="false"
        global="true"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.editors.columns.linenumbers"
        includeInMenu="false"
        name="%LineNumberRuler.name">
     <placement
           gravity="0.9">
     </placement>
     <targetClass
           class="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor">
     </targetClass>
  </column>
</extension>
```

Changing what is shown in existing columns is probably not possible.